# Android Background web service Issue

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I really need your help. I am building an Android app that needs a lot of HTTP requests such as logging to the server(check if user is exists or not) and storing the session to the database (user_sessions table), adding, updating and deleting records.

In my Login Activity, I have my AsyncTask (to check if user exits) and other background threads (logs the user session and download user info to database) . This is successful. Next, when I update the user info, it updates successfully. But what if I update using my web app? My should display the newly updated info on my android app. How can I resolve this problem?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
 private void logSessionToServer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            strUsername = etUsername.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair( TAG_USERNAME, strUsername ));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note it accepts POST method only
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_log_session,
                "POST", params);

            // check log cat from response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {

                    Log.d("", "Successfully logged session!");


                } else {
                    // failed 
                    Log.d("", "Not Successful!");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    thread.start();

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new record
 * */
class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.upload);
        pDialog.setTitle("Connecting to server");
        pDialog.setMessage("Validating login details..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        strUsername = etUsername.getText().toString();
        strPassword = etPassword.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair( TAG_USERNAME, strUsername ));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair( TAG_PASSWORD, strPassword ));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note it accepts POST method only
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login,
            "POST", params);


        // check log cat from response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {

                logSessionToServer(); // Save login to server

                saveUserInfoToDB(); // Save user info to DB

                saveUserloggedIn(); // Save user logged in to preference

                savePriestInfoToDB(); // Save priest to DB

                Log.d("", "Successful Login!");

                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed 

                new Thread()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                                        "Not Successful Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }.start();

                Log.d("", "Not Successful Login!");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;


    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

private void saveUserInfoToDB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){

            // Create the array 
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given website URL in JSONfunctions.class
            String result = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL(url_view_loggedUser_profile);

            try {
                JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
                 {  
                          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                          jb = (JSONObject)jr.get(i);
                          map.put(TAG_FIRSTNAME, jb.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME));
                          map.put(TAG_MIDDLENAME, jb.getString(TAG_MIDDLENAME));
                          map.put(TAG_LASTNAME, jb.getString(TAG_LASTNAME));
                          map.put(TAG_EMAIL, jb.getString(TAG_EMAIL));
                          map.put(TAG_AGE, jb.getString(TAG_AGE));
                          map.put(TAG_GENDER, jb.getString(TAG_GENDER));
                          map.put(TAG_USERNAME, jb.getString(TAG_USERNAME));
                          map.put(TAG_PASSWORD, jb.getString(TAG_PASSWORD));
                          map.put(TAG_BARANGAY, jb.getString(TAG_BARANGAY));
                          map.put(TAG_COMPLETEADDRESS, jb.getString(TAG_COMPLETEADDRESS));
                          map.put(TAG_CUS_ID, jb.getString(TAG_CUS_ID));
                          map.put(TAG_REG_DATE, jb.getString(TAG_REG_DATE));
                          map.put(TAG_BD_MONTH, jb.getString(TAG_BD_MONTH));
                          map.put(TAG_BD_DATE, jb.getString(TAG_BD_DATE));
                          map.put(TAG_BD_YEAR, jb.getString(TAG_BD_YEAR));
                          arraylist.add(map);

                          String strCusID = jb.getString(TAG_CUS_ID);
                          String strFname = jb.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
                          String strMname = jb.getString(TAG_MIDDLENAME);
                          String strLname = jb.getString(TAG_LASTNAME);
                          String strEmail = jb.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                          String strAge = jb.getString(TAG_AGE);
                          String strGender = jb.getString(TAG_GENDER);
                          String strUsername = jb.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                          String strPassword = jb.getString(TAG_PASSWORD);
                          String strBarangay = jb.getString(TAG_BARANGAY);
                          String strCompleteAddress = jb.getString(TAG_COMPLETEADDRESS);
                          String strRegDate = jb.getString(TAG_REG_DATE);
                          String strBDMonth = jb.getString(TAG_BD_MONTH);
                          String strBDDate = jb.getString(TAG_BD_DATE);
                          String strBDYear = jb.getString(TAG_BD_YEAR);

                          try{



                              dbHelper.insertEntry(strCusID, strFname, strMname, strLname, strEmail, 
                                      strAge, strGender, strUsername, strPassword, 
                                      strBarangay, strCompleteAddress, strRegDate, 
                                      strBDMonth, strBDDate, strBDYear);
                              Log.d("Response", "Successfully inserted record");


                          } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                              Log.d("Response", "Not successful");
                          }

                 }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    thread.start();

}

private void savePriestInfoToDB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){

            // Create the array 
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given website URL in JSONfunctions.class
            String result = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL_VIEW_PRIESTS);

            try {
                JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
                 {  
                          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                          jb = (JSONObject)jr.get(i);
                          map.put(TAG_P_ID, jb.getString(TAG_P_ID));
                          map.put(TAG_P_FIRSTNAME, jb.getString(TAG_P_FIRSTNAME));
                          map.put(TAG_P_MIDDLENAME, jb.getString(TAG_P_MIDDLENAME));
                          map.put(TAG_P_LASTNAME, jb.getString(TAG_P_LASTNAME));
                          map.put(TAG_P_EMAIL, jb.getString(TAG_P_EMAIL));
                          map.put(TAG_P_AGE, jb.getString(TAG_P_AGE));
                          map.put(TAG_P_ADDRESS, jb.getString(TAG_P_ADDRESS));
                          map.put(TAG_P_CONTACT, jb.getString(TAG_P_CONTACT));
                          map.put(TAG_P_STATUS, jb.getString(TAG_P_STATUS));
                          arraylist.add(map);

                          String strP_ID = jb.getString(TAG_P_ID);
                          String strP_Fname = jb.getString(TAG_P_FIRSTNAME);
                          String strP_Mname = jb.getString(TAG_P_MIDDLENAME);
                          String strP_Lname = jb.getString(TAG_P_LASTNAME);
                          String strP_Email = jb.getString(TAG_P_EMAIL);
                          String strP_Age = jb.getString(TAG_P_AGE);
                          String strP_Address = jb.getString(TAG_P_ADDRESS);
                          String strP_Status = jb.getString(TAG_P_STATUS);
                          String strP_Contact = jb.getString(TAG_P_CONTACT);

                          try{


                              dbHelper.insertPriest(strP_ID, strP_Fname, strP_Mname, 
                                      strP_Lname, strP_Email, strP_Age, 
                                      strP_Address, strP_Status, strP_Contact);
                              Log.d("Response - Priest", "Successfully inserted record");


                          } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                              Log.d("Response - Priest", "Not successful");
                          }

                 }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    thread.start();

}
```

Feel free to check out my codes and give feedback if this is the best practice for HTTP requests. I am new to Web Services so I really need your help. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think you have to check for an update from time to time. Best is if you use a thread which runs in background and checks like every 5 seconds or something.

Comment: @ZerO so what would be the best way to check it?

Comment: Strange mix of Threads and AsyncTasks. Use AsyncTasks only, Thread creation is expensive and certainly unnecessary when there's not even a loop inside them.

Comment: but there would be a loop inside?

Comment: @weston how can I let them do each task by using Asynctask? Can you provide some sample codes to do that?

Comment: You have an async task example in your post. Look how `LoginTask` works. Why can't the body of `logSessionToServer` be in a similar task?

Comment: whaaat... I didn't see that this whole thing is running in a thread. Why?

Comment: @weston can you help me simplify my code?

Comment: well, he just told you what to do. what else could he do, rewrite everything?

Comment: @ZerO no not really rewrite but give me some sample to do that. Because I'm new to AsyncTask I'm kinda confused though.

Comment: but you implemented an asyncTask? just do the same with logSessionToServer

Comment: yes I have implemented an asyncTask - LoginTask but in my LoginTask, can I call another AsyncTask inside of that?

Comment: BTW you can post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you want general review and improvement.

Comment: @weston okay will do that

Answer (score 0):

Well what I just said: you write a thread which downloads user-info every 5 seconds. then it compares the user info downloaded with the user info that is already stored on your device. if there is a difference, an update has been made, and your thread invokes a new download of the updated user info.

Comment: yes but where will I put the event to download user info every 5 seconds?

Comment: in the thread? do you know how a thread works and what it does? because if I look at your implementation, it seems you are still a bit unclear about this.